# dar formato a un input type number ponerle separador de miles y punto para el dicimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

tengo un input type number

```js
function darFormato(){
  //QUE EXPRECION REGULAR PUEDO HACER
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" onkeyup="darFormato()"  required>
```

la idea es que si agregan por ejemplo 101 
quede 101.00
si ingresan 90,500.00
si ingresan 105,700.00
y asi muchas gracias

Comment: Y porque una expresion regular?

Comment: pienso que es la mejor forma o si tienes una idea, podrías compartirla

Comment: una expresion regular sirve para comprobar si una cadena tiene un determinado formato, por eso pregunte que querrias hacer para darle formato a algo con una regexp?

Comment: comprendo, entonces como podría darle el formato deseado ?